# How to run id3lib dll library?

Tags: java, c++, mp3, id3

`id3lib` is an external library which I wanted to include in my code but it is showing build failed .Maybe, I am missing out some step.Please help!!
Or if there is any other such library(in java or c++) to parse mp3 headers,that would also do.

Comment: on linking it to my code,it shows the following error-can't create output/bin/debug..why so?have i missed out on anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Java ID3 Tag Library** but please try to find whether any JAR file is available that you can include. Currently, you are trying to use id3lib but I recommend you to check the dependencies as well if any which will not impact on your build. Else, any class or dependent libraries will cause a build failure if missing.

**Thanks!**

Comment: how do we actually include a library to our code snippet?